# How to Fetch Wordpress website database in android?

Tags: android, json, database, wordpress

I am new in android and creating a simple android application in which data should be fetched from wordpress website.I have used JSON Plugins(json-api.1.1.1, json-rest-api.1.2.2 & thermal-api.0.13.4)but i am getting result.I am not getting some pages in JSON format.The url of website is (http://fashion.pitechnologiesindore.com/product-category/dress/) I am trying to get Products in JSon But I am getting Blank Pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WooCommmerce then you should opt for WooCommmerce REST API v2 for getting the products and related data in json. 
Refer WooCommerce REST API Documentation v2 - http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#requests-responses

Comment: I have used WooCommmerce REST API v2 but i am getting error {"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"oauth_consumer_key parameter is missing"}]}

Comment: How do i solve this error?I have generated the user profile consumer and secret key.As well as i have downloaded the library from github (https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library) Where should i place this library file??